# Non-vanishing vector field on a manifold..

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

It is clear that the closed connected manifold admit non-vanishing vector field if and only if Euler characteristic of the manifold is zero. Let manifold M is non-compact or compact with boundary. Is it true M admits a non-vanishing vector field?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586862/non-vanishing-vector-fields-on-non-compact-manifolds .

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52023/is-there-a-poincare-hopf-index-theorem-for-non-compact-manifolds .