# Is the union of a compact and the relatively compact components of its complementary in a manifold compact?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, compactness

I was thinking of a way to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586862/non-vanishing-vector-fields-on-non-compact-manifolds) and I realised that for my approach the lemma from the title would be useful, and it´s an interesting question on its own. Obviously it is true if the manifold is $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I don´t see it in general. This is the precise question:

Let $M$ be a connected manifold and $X$ a compact inside it, then is the union of $X$ and all the relatively compact components of $M\setminus X$ compact?

Edit: After a few days (and asking a few people) I thought the question is more adequate for MO, and I asked it [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410049/is-the-union-of-a-compact-and-the-relatively-compact-components-of-its-complemen), where it has already been solved.

Comment: I just voted to close because I found a dupe, but this was a fun question to work on, and I'm glad you got an answer on MO.  10/10, would attempt and upvote again.